# How to get heading text on click in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple boxes and i want to get heading text on button click. Now i'm able to just button text. How can i do this?

My Code:-

```js
const Forms = () => {
  const  boxStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    padding:'10px',
    marginBottom:'15px'
  }
    const handleClick =( event) => {
        const theText = event.target.textContent;
        
        console.log("the text: ", theText);
    };

    return (
    <div>
    <div className="box" style={boxStyle}>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
     </div>
     
      <div className="box" style={boxStyle}>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Forms />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: try: `event.target.closest("h2").textContent`

Comment: `event.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.textContent;`

Comment: @Yousaf this is not working...

Comment: @RohitVerma i just noticed that `h2` element is a sibling element, not a parent element of the `button` element. Due to poor indentation of the code, i though `h2` was a parent element. `closest()` method would have worked if `h2` was a parent of the `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this, it is working for me.

```js
const Forms = () => {
  const  boxStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    padding:'10px',
    marginBottom:'15px'
  }
    const handleClick =( event) => {
        
        const theText = event.target.closest(".box").querySelector("h2").textContent;
        console.log("the text: ", theText);
    };

    return (
    <div>
    <div className="box" style={boxStyle}>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
     </div>
     
      <div className="box" style={boxStyle}>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Forms />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is working fine but can we use other way like `closet('h2')` instead of `previousElementSibling` because i have to select by `tagName`, `className` or `ID`

Comment: @RohitVerma you can use `closest` to get the parent `.box` element and then use `querySelector` to get the `h2` element: `event.target.closest(".box").querySelector("h2")`.

Comment: @RohitVerma I have updated the answer, please check. It is selected by tag now.

Comment: can we select class based instead of querySelector?

Comment: @RohitVerma I am trying to find the solution for the base with class :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do by adding ref to  tag and get text from ref.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html